# Consuta SQL de registros de hace 15 minutos

Tags: java, sql, db2

Tengo la siguiente SQL:

```
SELECT CCLIENCS, FOPERACI, XHORAOPE, XTACCION, XPUBLIFI 
FROM T9032300
WHERE XPUBLIFI <> 'K' AND XTACCION = 'B';
```

y en el **WHERE** tengo que añadir otro **AND** que contenga que la combinación **FOPERACI + XHORAOPE** sea de los últimos 15 minutos.

Ambos son de tipo **CHAR**, **FOPERACI** es una fecha con formato *AAAAMMDD* y **XHORAOPE** es la hora con formato *HHMMSS*. Me gustaria saber cómo puedo realizar dicha condicion.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Dado que no has guardado ambas columnas como una sola del tipo `DATETIME`, lo más simple ahora sería hacer precisamente eso: juntar ambas columnas en un solo dato, creando por ejemplo una marca del tiempo y a partir de ahí comparar si han pasado 15 minutos con respecto al momento actual.

Comment: Yo no puedo modifcar el nombre y el tipo de las columnas al no tener permiso.

Comment: Pues no hay otra que crear un objeto temporal (DATETIME o TIMESTAMP) uniendo los datos de ambas columnas y usarlo en el criterio del `WHERE`. Intenta eso y si tienes algún problema nos dices.

Comment: Si te refieres a crear una columna mas no puedo debido a los permisos. He visto el Convert pero no se si en DB2 funciona esto.

Comment: Me refiero a hacerlo de forma dinámica, en la consulta. O bien puedes hacer una doble comparación: `WHERE (columnaFecha = fechaActual AND columnaHora =< intervalo15Minutos)` dado que no uso DB2 no sé exactamente la notación para la fecha actual y los intervalos,